# Nasal Congestion for newborn less than 2 months

Tags: sleep, newborn

My newborn wakes up upset from blocked nose although I keep a humidifier in the room to remove any congestions and keep her warm.

Not sure what to do to prevent this as she wakes up upset from it.

Comment: Have you tried nose frida before bedtime and every time your child wakes up?

Comment: How do you know that humidifier results in optimal humidity? Not too high and not too low.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Nose Frida works best with saline which i dont want to keep using it everytime this happens.  I actually thought of measuring the room humidity so I bought the hygrometer which is used to measure humidity in the room I always keep it below 60%

Comment: @A_K - May I ask why you object to frequent use of saline? Saline is safe and effective; it's basically mucus without the proteins that make mucus "mucusy". It thins mucus, shrinks swollen nasal mucosa a bit making nose-breathing easier, is all-natural, and cheap (you can make it at home and make sure it's sterile.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse the dr recommended not to use it often to prevent nose irritation. I also thought it could cause future sinus

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you!